How to use SV_ViewportArrayIndex semantic in a geometry shader?
I want to render multiple viewports，but the settings for the vertex shader don't seem to take effect, the second of my two viewports is still a black screen.
I have tried to do like below
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewports[2];

    viewports[0].TopLeftX = 0;
    viewports[0].TopLeftY = 0;
    viewports[0].Width = width_ / 2;
    viewports[0].Height = height_;
    viewports[0].MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewports[0].MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    


    viewports[1].TopLeftX = width_ / 2;
    viewports[1].TopLeftY = 0;
    viewports[1].Width = width_ / 2;
    viewports[1].Height = height_;
    viewports[1].MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewports[1].MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    
    deviceContext->RSSetViewports(2, viewports);
    deviceContext->DrawIndexed(indicesSize, 0, 0);

Then I use SV_ViewportArrayIndex semantic in a geometry shader, but I don't know exactly how to set. Here is my way and it dosen't work.
struct VSOut
{
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD;
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    uint viewportIndex : CUSTOM_VIEWPORT_INDEX; 
};

struct GSOut
{
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD;
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    uint viewportIndex : SV_ViewportArrayIndex; 
};

[maxvertexcount(3)]
void main_GS(triangle VSOut input[3], inout TriangleStream<GSOut> TriStream)
{
    GSOut output;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        output.pos = input[i].pos;
        output.tex = input[i].tex;
        output.viewportIndex = input[i].viewportIndex; 

        TriStream.Append(output);
    }
    TriStream.RestartStrip();
}

Does anyone konw where is my problem?
